# Windows time locales to PHP locales

Tags: php, windows, timezone

I am developing a PHP application that is provided with timestamps from a Dynamics CRM. Each timestamp is provided in ISO8601 format, so we get the the time relative to UST.

Now, we also get a timezone number. This is needed so we can display the timezone properly. For example, we may be given 16:00+1 in the Summer with a timezone of 85 (UK, I bvelieve), so that would be displayed as 16:00 BST.

PHP when displaying a formatted date and time using the DateTime class, needs timezones in this kind of format: "Europe/London".

Now, what I need, is a translation from the Dynamic's "85" to PHP's "Europe/London". I don't know what either of those two lists are called (85 looks like something I remember from DOS days), and I cannot find any mapping tables or lists anywhere.

In short: we have - or can derive - essentially unix timestamps on PHP, and are given a "timezone" number from MS Dynamics, and need to be able to display that timestamp in a format appropriate to the timezone, e.g. "16:00 BST", "15:00 GMT", "11:00 EST".

Comment: Going from "+0200" it's pretty hard to go to "Europe/Amsterdam" as it could also be "Africa/Cairo".

Comment: Yes, I realise that. The offset combines both the timezone offset and any day-light saving hours that may be in effect on that date, so you could not even tell the difference between say, Spain in the Summer and UK in the Winter. It is the "timezone" integer that is supplied with the timezone, perhaps also taking the offset into account, that I am hoping will answer the question of (perhaps) a best-guess human-readable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a table that explains the meaning of your code 85:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226764(v=sql.80).aspx

But you cannot define the location (Eu/London) in the timezone exactly.

Comment: Okay, this looks promising. This gives the standard offset from UCT for each of these timezones, so I have a name, and given the offset in the time supplied, can tell if daylight saving hours are in operation. Now I suppose I need to find a table of the names of each of these timezones are different times of the year. For example, "85" is listed as "GMT Time" here. However, the time provided may be 15:00+1 i.e "15:00 BST" in the Summer or 15:00 i.e "15:00 GMT" in the Winter. Those two names - GMT or BST - are what would make sense to a user reading the times.

Comment: Is 85 *really* "GMT Time", or is it "UK Time"? The date I am supplied with includes daylight-saving offsets with the time, so it does not look like GMT to me - GMT does not have offsets - UK time has the offsets during the Summer. On the Dynamics CRM, the user enters "15:00" with a the Summer date and selects "GMT Time" as its timezone. I don't get 15:00 GMT - I am sent 15:00+1, i.e. 14:00 GMT + one hour daylight saving. The naming all seems very contradictory.

Comment: GMT should be correct, even if it includes the "summertime hour". GMT is not necessarily the blank world time. see UTC instead.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer. It does not give me the full answer, but I suspect answer is "it is more complicated than that". This one gives me a good start in the right direction though. Thanks.